# Check for duplicates based on two columns

Tags: php, sql-server

So I have an employee table as follows:

```
empid | companyid | empnum | ...
  1   |     1     |    1   | ...
  2   |     1     |    2   | ...
  3   |     1     |    3   | ...
  4   |     2     |    1   | ...
  5   |     2     |    2   | ...
```

Every employee entry on the table gets a unique ID (empid) that is generated automatically by MSSQL. I have a PHP application that takes a CSV file as input with a "master list" of employees. However that CSV file only has the columns from "empnum" right-ward (it does NOT contain companyid, or obviously employeeid). companyid is added when I iterate through each line of the CSV file. The CSV *should* only contain employees that are not in the database yet, but there is no guarantee, so I need to check to make sure the employee is not there before inserting. The verification method is to make sure that for this particular companyid (let's say we're inserting for companyid = 1), there is not already a matching empnum in the table. So if I had a CSV file with this data, it would be valid:

```
empnum, ...
4, ...
```

However if I had a CSV file with this data, it would NOT be valid:

```
empnum, ...
3, ...
```

Since 3 already exists as an empnum for companyid=1, the ENTIRE import should fail. In the PHP application, I have:

```
try {
   db->beginTransaction();
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      //SQL TO INSERT ROW   
   }
   db->commit();
} catch (PDO Exception) {
   db->rollBack();
}
```

What SQL should I use to insert the row so that it will cause an exception if an empnum already exists for that companyid? What database changes would I need to make? My initial thoughts are:

Option 1 - Insert into a temporary table, then run a select query that joins the two tables on matching values in companyid/empnum, if it returns rows > 0, throw an exception. PRO: Only 1 select. CON: Everything is inserted to the temp table THEN dumped into real table IF it passes select = lots of wasted time if it fails

Option 2- Do a select statement based on the current row, if it returns rows > 0, throw an exception, otherwise insert into real table. PRO: You catch failures as soon as they happen so you can potentially save yourself time. CON: Your queries have now increased by (2x-1) so you have a lot of extra overhead if you succeed!

So my questions would be:
- What's the best option (1, 2, or something else entirely)?
- Can I somehow get MSSQL to throw the exception when inserting?

Comment: This isn't the exact code but you can get an idea:
$nextEmpnum=("SELECT MAX empnum FROM employee_table WHERE companyid=".$company_id)+1
"INSERT INTO employee_table values (".$nextEmpnum.",".$company_id

Comment: Sorry...I should have specified better. I'm not trying to CREATE a unique id for the empnum. empnum will be supplied by the company that's importing the data. I simply need to see if the employee already exists on the table (based on a combination of companyid and empnum)

Comment: Also, not sure why this question got a downvote. If you downvoted, please say why!

Comment: While I am not the one who down-voted, I would guess the length of the question is the reason for it.  Some people think if you cannot explain your question in a short paragraph then it is a bad question, regardless of complexity or content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is the 'standard' way of loading data (certainly in my world). Your temp table is actually called a 'staging' table. This will be much quicker than checking row by row (look up RBAR).

In fact what will always take the most time is doing things row by row.

A mudmap performance comparison:

Option 1:

1. Do your initial insert into the table row by row (slow)
2. Capture duplicates between tables with a single SELECT query (fast)
3. If succesful, copy staging into live table (fast)

Option 2:

1. Load your data out of your CSV row by row (medium)
2. Whilst doing this, Capture duplicates row by row by selecting each time (slow)

What's not clear is what do you do when you find a duplicate in option 2? Do you want to roll back all of the other records or do you want to notify the user and continue?

Comment: At this time, I have 3 "screens" they walkthrough. First is to choose the file and upload it. Second displays a preview of all the data by reading the CSV. They hit Import and then my question takes effect. Thinking more on this, perhaps during the preview, I could somehow flag anything that appears as a duplicate and prevent them from importing?

Comment: To me, this would lend weight to having a staging table, as you need to 'stage' it before you load it into the final table. And you could transfer it into the final table with INSERT INTO FinalTable SELECT * FROM StaginTable WHERE Status = 'Import'. Just be aware you are adding  complexity for the user and they don't always like that! How does the uploaded file get into the database at the moment - is it bulk loaded or do you have some PHP code that goes through line by line and inserts it? how many records?

Comment: Another reason for a staging table is for when someone has txt in a numeric field or a badly formatted date. You can load everything into a staging table with only text fields and add this data cleansing process. Otherwise if you just try and load you CSV data directly into your target able it's possible you'll have data conversion issues as well as duplication issues.

Comment: I agree that staging is probably best. I WAS going to insert into the staging column line by line and add a flag to the preview table showing that there is a problem with that row (such as it already exists), but now I'm thinking that I'll just import everything into the staging table as is, then run a bunch of queries to check for bad data and perhaps update an "error" column if any have issues. Then display the data from the staging table so it can be corrected before import. If multiple users are importing data the same time, will I have issues with a staging table?

Comment: yes you will have issues with multiple users. There are various workarounds such as add a user column, or implement some kind of manual locking mechanism. But these are all a but unreliable. For reliable multi user scenarios you might have to discount the staging approach.

Comment: perhaps I just name the staging table username+"temp" since they can only be importing one thing at a time?

Comment: Or you more flexible is you just create one table and add a user column to it. Then you don't need to go and create a table for every new user.